# cocoa arc4random OS X 10.6

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, arc4random

I have created a simple Custom View Application for Lion. Now a friend tested it using Snow Leopard and couldn't launch it. Sadly I don't have the Exception. The only thing I know is, that it's about the function-call of arc4random, which is not available in her version.
I actually can't imagine, that such an essential function was introduced in Lion (yeah, im rather new to cocoa...), so do you guys have any idea, what that could be about?
I'll try to get the Exception Details, but I am pretty much under time pressure...

Comment: The man page dates back to OS X v10.3. What makes you think that `arc4random()` isn’t available on 10.6? Do you have an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem with my app crashing on Snow Leopard with the crash report saying:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Symbol not found: _arc4random_buf
Referenced from: <myApp binary>
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

I had to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) several times until I realized that `arc4random()` itself is available since 10.4 but `arc4random_buf()` is only available since 10.7. If you use the `arc4random_buf()` function (like me) it will not run on 10.6.

So, I just replaced the `arc4random_buf()` function with the following C-code:

```
void myArc4RandBuf(uint8_t* randomBytes, size_t length) {
    size_t intBufLength = (length/4)+1;
    uint32_t randomInts[intBufLength];        
    for (int i = 0; i < intBufLength; i++) {
        randomInts[i] = arc4random();
    }
    memcpy(randomBytes, randomInts, length);
}
```

That is probably a bit slower because `arc4random()` is called several times, but it works on every Mac OS from 10.4 to 10.8.